# Is our universe stronger than the alternate universe?

Tags: fringe, parallel-universe

In *Fringe*, It seemed that our universe is stronger than the alternate universe, because whenever someone went to their universe from ours it caused their universe's geological membrane damage,  requiring them to quarantine the area/facility and create an amber.

On the other hand, when someone travels from the alternative universe into ours it does not damage our universe. Walter, Olivia, Shape Shifters and observers have traveled from Walternates Universe in to our universe.

Does this mean that our universe is stronger with less soft/weaken spots than the Walternate's universe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Walternate universe has been damaged repeatedly from abuses to their spacetime fabric. When Walter first visited, think of it like the difference between and entry and an exit wound- small damage here, but massive damage over there. Their universe began to destabilize immediately.

So yes, in a sense it would seem that our universe was "stronger" but that ends up being illusory. With all of the operatives who have come to our universe over the years, our universe is also shown to have begun to destabilize. It took longer because we had 25 years or so without having agents busting in to our universe, but make no mistake: the only difference in the stability of our universes is the time from first damage, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it shown that our universe is stronger and less soft/weaken spots than the walternate`s universe?

**NO.** Unfortunately Fringe has hundreds of inconsistencies and plot holes and the reason for them is the fact that J.J. Abrams didn't think the progression of the show through when he started it.

From an [interview](http://www.hitfix.com/the-fien-print/j-j-abrams-briefly-discusses-the-end-of-fringe):

> **HitFix**: And when you started with that pilot, how much of where we ended up do you think you had in your mind?
>
> **J.J. Abrams**: We knew alternate universes. We knew The Observers. We knew, even when Walter first sees Peter at the institution and he
>   checks his eyes, we knew what was going on and why. But what we didn't
>   know was sort of... Everything. We didn't know how crazy and wild and
>   big it would go. We didn't, of course, know the jump forward in the
>   fifth season. We didn't know some of the details of the Cortexiphan
>   stuff with Olivia, but we knew that there was something she had gone
>   through. You always have the best idea at the time and you think,
>   "That's kinda where we're gonna go" and the closer you get to doing
>   it, the better idea comes up and you go, "Oh my God, what about that?"
>   So it's always a leap of faith a little bit.

In addition to that there are a lot of sites out there that have created whole lists containing all the plot holes, continuity mistakes and inconsistencies of Fringe. Some examples:

- [TVTropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/Fringe)
- [MovieMistakes.com](http://www.moviemistakes.com/tv7641)
- [Fringe-Forums.com](http://fringe-forum.com/forums/showthread.php?15444-Fringe-s-Major-Plot-Holes)

---

**Personal comment**: I'm not sure on which season are you on but these plot holes start coming up on the second half of the third season. Up until that point the show looks extremely well thought.